# Potential problems with virtual drive larger than 2tb?

Tags: windows-server-2012

We are setting up a server for a client of ours which is using an Intel raid controller with 4 x WD 4TB RE drives configured for RAID 6. Ideally we would like to configure with 2 virtual disks; one being for the OS at 2TB, and the second virtual drive for data using the remaining 5.275TB.

So far we have configured the OS drive using MBR, and the data as GPT and all is well. A colleague of mine seems to think that this could potentially be an issue for applications (Microsoft or third party) that are unable to utilize the full 5.275TB data partition. Our client will be using Hyper-V and a majority of the data drive will store the virtual machines, VHDXs, and so forth.

As it sits right now the system is functioning normally with what was described above. If anyone can shed some light on any potential issues you foresee, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: RAID 6 and not RAID 10?

Comment: `1.` 2TB for the host OS seems like overkill. If the host OS is only going to have the Hyper-V role installed you could provision that virtual disk to be a lot smaller (my Hyper-V hosts barely use 30GB for the host OS). `2.` Applications don't know or care about the underlying virtual disk. `3.` the 5 TB virtual disk isn't going to be used by a single VM. `4.` The VM's don't know anything about the underlying virtual disk. `5.` You're putting all of your eggs in one basket. Why not use two smaller physical disks in a RAID 10 for the host OS and use x number of larger disks for your VM storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for virtualization workloads, I strongly suggest you to use RAID10 rather than RAID6. Moreover, 2 TB for the OS partition is way too much.

Anyway, back to original question: if you format the second vdisk as GPT partition, you will have no problem to use all the available space. The maximum single file size a NTFS volume will support is [16 TB or 256 TB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), depending on the version.

Comment: That's what I thought, just needed some clarification. I would have used a much smaller partition for OS (500 GB), but for some reason my colleague wants the extra room (his reasoning is - just in case).

Answer (score 0):

As Joeqwerty said, applications don't care about MBR or GPT. Operating systems do. When you select GPT to initialize a disk, you get a warning that old operating systems will not be able to read the disk. You might encounter this issue if you use a boot CD for troubleshooting. With your current configuration, you'll be able to boot with anything and see the C: drive, so you'll be fine.